# How can I print a full gridview area via a custom print window?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, css, gridview

I'm in the process of creating a custom GridView data Print window that is designed to just print out the gridview area. One button will print out the grid view for the current window and the other button for all the records in the GridView.  As the code stands now, when the button is clicked (Printing the current page and all of the records respectively) the preview window shows all the records in the GridView perfectly (23 columns including two command fields on either side of the GridView).  However, when the job is printed out the grid view is chopped (only shows about half of the grid) no matter what printer or CSS/Formatting settings I tweak.

The two challenges I'm encountering is that 1) I am unable to print the full gridview in portrait or landscape and 2) my javascript is pretty weak.  How can I tweak the following code so that when the gridview prints, the FULL grid is printed?

If more information is needed, please do not hesitate to ask.

Here is the code I have behind my aspx file for the print buttons.

```
protected void PrintCurrentPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
GridView1.PagerSettings.Visible = false;
GridView1.DataBind();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
string gridHTML = sw.ToString().Replace("\"", "'")
.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){");
sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0");
sb.Append(",top=0,width=3000,height=600,status=0');");
sb.Append("printWin.document.write(\"");
sb.Append(gridHTML);
sb.Append("\");");
sb.Append("printWin.document.close();");
sb.Append("printWin.focus();");
sb.Append("printWin.print();");
sb.Append("printWin.close();};");
sb.Append("</script>");
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GridPrint", sb.ToString());
GridView1.PagerSettings.Visible = true;
GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

And here is the code for printing all the records.

```
protected void PrintAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
GridView1.DataBind();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
string gridHTML = sw.ToString().Replace("\"", "'")
    .Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){");
sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0");
sb.Append(",top=0,width=3000,height=600,status=0');");
sb.Append("printWin.document.write(\"");
sb.Append(gridHTML);
sb.Append("\");");
sb.Append("printWin.document.close();");
sb.Append("printWin.focus();");
sb.Append("printWin.print();");
sb.Append("printWin.close();};");
sb.Append("</script>");
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GridPrint", sb.ToString());
GridView1.AllowPaging = true;
GridView1.DataBind();


}
```

Comment: do u mean that in two cases "printall" & "printCurrentPage" you get the current page printed only ?

Comment: Sorry, in both cases when the button is clicked a formatted print preview window (all the other web page cosmetics are stripped out) appears that only shows the full GridView Area followed immediately by an OS 'Print' window asking for what printer I want to use to print out along with printer options.  When the 'Print' button in the OS print window is clicked only half of the print area is printed out.

Comment: I should note that there are 23 columns total including two command fields on either side of the GridView.

Comment: what we normally do in this cases is actually have two `<table>`'s that we hide from display and show on print using just CSS rules... It will be easier to maintain as well, and no need to pop up windows (they are terribly annoying for the user)

Comment: @balexandre - I've been playing around with CSS options earlier today but couldn't get anything to work properly. Perhaps, I'm not tweaking the right settings.  Could you provide a sample of what you're referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the grid is that big in width, there is nothing, by default that you can do to print it all in the same page...

But, that's not bad news, in fact, there are several articles that help you choose and show the same grid in different ways upon the user print it.

The best way I see would be to show more information in one column, group them into something else and that is relevant to the user, and try it out...

This is just an example, and I have no idea what are you printing, but, instead of having all fields for a customer in one line, group them as:

```
Customer                  | Sales Responsible        | ...
------------------------------------------------------------------
Bruno Alexandre           | Techie Joe               | ...
My Street not yours, 56   | 43 sales this month      | ...
DK-1400 København         | 450.000€ per sale (avg)  | ...
```

and then you can decorate that table with a `class` of `table-print` where:

```
<style>
@media screen
{
  table-print {display:none;}
}
@media print
{
  table-print {display:block;}
}
@media screen,print
{
  ...
}
</style>
```

after that, read how to deal with page breaks:

> [How to deal with page breaks when printing a large HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763639/how-to-deal-with-page-breaks-when-printing-a-large-html-table)

There is even the [Printliminator](http://css-tricks.com/print-better-with-the-printliminator/) to help users disable what they don't want to print...

Answer (score 0):

To change the direction of GridView to RTL:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
hw.AddStyleAttribute(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Direction, "rtl");
```