# Gridview column not changing width size

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, width

I can't make this GridView column change its width, I have tried this:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ABC" HeaderText="ABC" SortExpression="ABC"  ControlStyle-Width="200%">
```

Or as pixels:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ABC" HeaderText="ABC" SortExpression="ABC"  ControlStyle-Width="500px">
```

Or this inside the Boundfield tags:

```
<ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="500px"/>
```

Also tried this on code-behind:

```
Protected Sub GridView3_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView3.RowDataBound
    e.Row.Cells(7).Width = 500
End Sub
```

How do I get it right?

Answer (score 4):

Here is how it can be done.
I am re-sizing the columns who having property : Visible = True

```
Private Sub GridViewColumnsrResize(ByVal aspectratio As Integer, ByVal gv As DataGridView)
    Try
        Dim col_count As Integer = gv.Columns.Count
        For j As Integer = 0 To col_count - 1
            If gv.Columns(j).Visible = True Then
                gv.Columns(j).Width = gv.Columns(j).Width * aspectratio
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        'output ex
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: This will resize each and every column inside the given grid-view with given width as aspectratio

Answer (score 0):

I just posted this related thread yesterday with a similar issue.  Short answer is you can't.  There is a workaround as noted in this thread (at the bottom):

[How can I print a full gridview area via a custom print window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572059/how-can-i-print-a-full-gridview-area-via-a-custom-print-window)

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion** if you want the value to come in one line , for that you are increasing width then you can try this:
add a `cssClass` to you `Gridview` like `cssClass=gridContainer`,
add in the `.css` file:

```
 .gridContainer
  {
     white-space:nowrap;
  }
```

for more option, look [white-space property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by setting a fixed width for the GridView itself, it may not be for a specific column but it shares its width among all the GridView columns, thus expanding the column I wanted to expand.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource4" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="Gridview" Width="800px">
```