# iText Cut between pages in PDF from HTML table

Tags: itext

I did search a lot in google and docs but can't find a solution for this problem, maybe can you guys help me with this?

I have a pdf from html export and my table data is split between the pages, look at this image:

[image: table]

This is a html to pdf convert export, I am not building this table in the PDF, look:

```
String htmlString = getTableHtml(tableData);

// Create a buffer to hold the cleaned up HTML
ByteArrayOutputStream htmlOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

// Clean up the HTML to be well formed
HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
CleanerProperties props = cleaner.getProperties();
TagNode node = cleaner.clean(htmlString);
new PrettyXmlSerializer(props).writeToStream(node, htmlOutputStream);

// Create the PDF
ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocumentFromString(new String(htmlOutputStream.toByteArray()));
renderer.layout();
ByteArrayOutputStream pdfOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
renderer.createPDF(pdfOutputStream);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you show us some code?

Comment: I put the code in the desctiprion @AlexisPigeon

Comment: Did you fix it?? if yes, can you share the solution?

Answer (score 2):

it helped me

> ```
> <style>
> @media print
> {
>   table { page-break-after:auto }
>   tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
>   td    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
>   thead { display:table-header-group }
>   tfoot { display:table-footer-group }
> }
> </style>
> ```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7763286