# How to print a HTML table over multiple pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, html-table

I have a HTML table with quite a lot of rows.

When trying to print it, it fills the whole page but cuts off at the bottom WITHOUT showing the rest on further pages.

Is there some way (using CSS or Javascript) to ensure that all data is printed (on multiple pages)?

Note: The table is within a , which I think causes this anomaly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777317/printing-html-table-with-many-columns-rows-using-css-layout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777317/printing-html-table-with-many-columns-rows-using-css-layout)