# HTML: Printing Large Tables

Tags: html, css, printing, printing-web-page

I am printing a large table which is 100 rows x 100 columns, however it doesn't automatically page-break.

What I wanted to happen is to format the print output displaying the complete columns and with its defined width and font size. I managed to print the complete rows however, the other columns are missing.

[image: print]

What I am using is Google Chrome.

My code

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>sdfsfsdf</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            page-break-inside:auto 
        }
        tr    { 
            page-break-inside:avoid; 
            page-break-after:auto 
        }
        thead { 
            display:table-header-group 
        }
        th, td {
            border: black 1px solid;
            padding-left: 5px;
            padding-right: 5px;
            min-width: 200px;
        }
        @page {
            size: legal landscape;
            margin: 1cm;

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <?php
                // table headers
                for($x=1 ; $x<=100; $x++) {
                    echo '<th>Header ' . $x . '</th>';
                }
              ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
                //table body data
                for($y=1 ; $y<=100; $y++) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                    for($x=1 ; $x<=100; $x++) {
                        echo '<td>data ' . $y . ' - '. $x . '</td>';
                    }
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
              ?>
    </tbody>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The accepted answer in this SO -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777317/printing-html-table-with-many-columns-rows-using-css-layout might help you.

Comment: I followed that however, it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @AaronAlfonso Did you find any solution?

Comment: @DeepakBandi the solution I made was export to XLS. there's no way I found so far.

Comment: @AaronAlfonso Thanks for the update.