# media print page break print pdf

Tags: php, css

I found many related in google and stackoverflow but it is not effect to my result.
My data over 40000 row, i want print auto next page and fix data break row.

and set page number for every page.

```
<table cellspacing="0" class="table table_print" border="1">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Num</tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Jan</th>
    <th>Feb</th>
    <th>Mar</th>
    <th>Apr</th>
    <th>May</th>
    <th>Jun</th>
    <th>Jul</th>
    <th>Aug</th>
    <th>Sep</th>
    <th>Oct</th>
    <th>Nov</th>
    <th>Dec</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" scope="rowgroup"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
    <td rowspan="2" scope="rowgroup"><?php echo $name; ?></td>
    <td rowspan="2" scope="rowgroup"><?php echo $address; ?></td>
    <td rowspan="2" scope="rowgroup"><?php echo $contact; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['jan_price']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['feb_price']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['mar_price']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['apr_price']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['may_price']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['jun_price']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['jul_price']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['aug_price']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['sep_price']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['oct_price']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['nov_price']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['des_price']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['jan_grand']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['feb_grand']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['mar_grand']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['apr_grand']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['may_grand']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['jun_grand']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['jul_grand']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['aug_grand']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['sep_grand']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['oct_grand']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['nov_grand']; ?></td>
    <td scope="row"><?php echo $data[$i]['des_grand']; ?></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I try many with `page-break-after: always;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-before: avoid;`

but it's not work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26777317/printing-html-table-with-many-columns-rows-using-css-layout

Answer (score 1):

To who meet the same problem as me, I solve it by set limit row per page print

```
.table_print tbody tr:nth-of-type(32n){page-break-after: always;}
```