# Printing html tables, preventing rows from spanning multiple pages

Tags: css, printing, webkit

I generate html programmatically in order to have it rendered nicely for printing.

I have to print tables that may span several pages. This poses some challenges such as preventing cell contents to spread over two pages like this:

[image]

I found a solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8712756/43615), which uses `page-break-inside:avoid`, along with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12934695/43615), which uses `display: block` for the `<tr>` elements in order to prevent them from getting split up vertically.

However, this also causes the rows not to vertically align with each other any more. How do I fix that?

Here's how it should look (and how the browser renders it on-screen):

[image]

And here's what it renders for printing:

[image]

How do I make the printout aligned, the samew as it's aligned on the screen, without having to lose the `display: block` ability to keep cells vertically intact at page breaks? It has to work in Webkit (Safari) on macOS.

Here's the complete html code. It spans two pages so that one can check whether individual cells appear half on one and half on the next page (which is not desired):

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><style type="text/css">
th, td { border: 1px solid #aaa; }
@media print {
  table, tr, td, th {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
  tr {
    display: block;
    page-break-before: auto;
  }
}
</style></head>
<body>
<table style="width:40%">
  <tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th></tr>
  <tr><td>more text<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br></td><td>more text</td><td>more text</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

**Update:**

I also tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26898133/43615) which uses `div` instead of `table`. This gives slightly different results when printing, but still bad (now the cell heights are wrong, too):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding

```
td, th {
  width: 10000px;
}
```

inside `@media print { }` did the trick to make the example code work.

Now the printed columns are properly aligned again, and each row stays on a single page, never spanning two pages.

Works in current versions of Webkit (Safari), FF and Chrome (all tested on macOS only).

**Caveat:**

Unfortunately, the above is not fool proof. It only works in this example because the cells in each row have the same width.

Once those widths are random, an over-reaching pixel width like 10000px is messing up the columns again.

The only solution I found around this is to provide actual widths that are to be used. Since this is for printing, and since I know that I want to print to a specific paper format (e.g. DIN A4 or US Letter), I can specify the column width precisely with certainty.

So, while this solution is not a good one for a web page view in a browser on-screen, where the total width can vary, it's a good solution for printing, as long as the target print size can be predicted.

Here is the complete html code, setting the column widths to 4cm, 2cm and 3cm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><style type="text/css">
th, td { border: 1px solid #aaa; }
@media print {
  table, tr, td, th {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
  tr {
    display: block;
    page-break-before: auto;
  }
  td:nth-child(1), th:nth-child(1) {
    width: 4cm;
  }
  td:nth-child(2), th:nth-child(2) {
    width: 2cm;
  }
  td:nth-child(3), th:nth-child(3) {
    width: 3cm;
  }
}
</style></head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th></tr>
  <tr><td>more text<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br></td><td>more text</td><td>more text</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1 adasd<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1asd<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>xsdsdfsf</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2 asda asdas<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>xasdada</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4 asdasd <br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution to this problem that does not depend on fixed column widths is to wrap each cell's content in a `display:block` element and set this to `page-break-inside: avoid`. If you don't want to alter the HTML in the first place, you can alter the DOM dynamically on load. As I'm lazy, I'm using jQuery in the following example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><style type="text/css">
th, td { border: 1px solid #aaa; }
@media print {
  td hack {
    display: block;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
}
</style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        $( "td" ).wrapInner( "<hack></hack>" );
    })  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th></tr>
  <tr><td>more text<br>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br></td><td>more text</td><td>more text</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1 adasd<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1asd<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>xsdsdfsf</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2 asda asdas<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br></td><td>xasdada</td><td>x</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1<br>2<br>3<br>4 asdasd <br>5<br>6<br></td><td>x</td><td>x</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
```

The result will look a bit different:

[image: Print Preview]

You see the following issues:

- the row already starts at the previous page (which can be a seen as an indication for the table is still continuing)
- the content of columns B and C is vertically centred according to the total height of the row spanning both pages so it appears to be top aligned towards the highest cell in column A

But the solution does work with WebKit browsers and still renders as a normal table.