# How to cut table on print

Tags: html, printing, html-table

I have a table which is more larger than my page, so when I print it I have just one part of the table. Is there any method to break the table automatically before the end of the print page ?

I try with page-break-inside and page-break-after but doesn't find the way to make this works.

Comment: Have you checked the question [Printing HTML table with many columns/rows using CSS layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26777317/6002174)?

Comment: But they use div, my table is made with table, thead, tbody, etc.