# knpsnappybundle create issue at page break

Tags: html, symfony, pdf, twig, page-break

i am using simfony2.x and i want to use `knpsnappybundle` budle to create pdf file from html. so i had use this configuration,

```
knp_snappy:
pdf:
    enabled:    true
    binary:     "\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe\""
    options:    []
image:
    enabled:    true
    binary:     "\"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltoimage.exe\""
    options:    []
```

then after in my contoller i am using this service like

```
$html = $this->renderView('MyBundle:MyController:view.html.twig', array(
        'project' => $project,
        'answers' => $answers
    ));
    return new Response(
        $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($html), 200, array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="test.pdf"',
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
        )
    );
```

it create pdf file for me but pdf contain wrong design at the time of page break, this is the screen cap of my pdf

[image: My Pdf look like this]

and here is my actual Html (from which, this pdf is generated) [image: Html Output]

so can anyone help me to avoid this issue of html page break ?

thanks

Comment: take a look at this: [page-break](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763639/how-to-deal-with-page-breaks-when-printing-a-large-html-table)

Comment: Thanks, but it won't work for me