# How to prevent a table row from breaking at the end of the page in the print view?

Tags: html, css

I tried to use `page-break-inside` and `page-break-after` to prevent the table rows (Which I set to `display: block`) from breaking at the end of the page. But it doesn't seem to work. Here's a screenshot :

[image]

Here's the sample code I used for it : http://codepen.io/THpubs/pen/YWNWvr

Any idea how to fix it?

I tried the code in the question [How to deal with page breaks when printing a large HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763639/how-to-deal-with-page-breaks-when-printing-a-large-html-table) But still I get the same results.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763639/how-to-deal-with-page-breaks-when-printing-a-large-html-table

Comment: @GermanoPlebani I tried the code in that question but still I get the same results.

Comment: If you read all comments it's not possible with all browser.