# How to write <t t-if=" " > condition for an html <span> to check report page no

Tags: python, qweb

I have created a custom invoice report in odoo10. But when the table contents (invoice items/products) increases, the table goes to second page with disturbed formatting.

I want to make the second page to show the header, table headings with rest items on the second page like in default invoice reports in odoo.

How can I achieve this! I have created the whole Invoice Report in one table ie   with multiple rowspans and colspans.

The second option is, I can write a condition to check if the report includes the second page, then the Total amount and rest part should be displayed on the second page. So how can I check, if the invoice is including the second page?

something like :

```
<t t-if="span='class='page''>1">
```

Below is the default page div of odoo10 .

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-3 text-right">
   <ul class="list-inline">
      <li><span class="page"/></li>
      <li>/</li>
      <li><span class="topage"/></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Below is my custom report screenshot:
[Custom Invoice Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdYNb.png)

Below is the default odoo invoice report layout screenshot:

[Default Odoo Invoice Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZv14.png)

Please advise how can I achieve this. Alternate advise are welcome.

PS: I tried the page breaks for html page but still it doesn't have any effect on the pdf print.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with page breaks when printing a large HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763639/how-to-deal-with-page-breaks-when-printing-a-large-html-table)

Comment: I have already referred the above link for page breaks. But didn't get any solution for my problem.

Comment: After modified the report table, I used the css mentioned in above link. And it worked. Thanks for your help.