# Printing table don´t break the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I'm trying to print a table with many columns, it's not breaking to the next page, i try either in chrome or firefox.
Has anyone ever experienced this.

[Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH1U0.jpg)

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763639/how-to-deal-with-page-breaks-when-printing-a-large-html-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please try to put to main container this

```
.itemContainer{
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        display: flex;
    }
    .item{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;

    }
```

where you template like this:

```
  <div class="itemContainer">
        <div class="item">
            <div> sdvsdvs</div>
            <div> sdvsdvs</div>
            <div> sdvsdvs</div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div> sdvsdvs</div>
            <div> sdvsdvs</div>
            <div> sdvsdvs</div>
            </div>
</div>
```

for more examples, you can check [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Hi vitaly. 
This solution worked fine with divs but I am using tables. I'll be rewriting for div to be able to test.
Thank you very much

Comment: if it helps please set is as answered.