# Automatically add new page when content goes at the end of the Page?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, printing

In my application, I want to print some contents in a A4 size page [Page break](http://jsfiddle.net/mturjak/2wk6Q/1949/)

```
<div class="book">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="subpage">[[Page 1/2]]</div>    
    </div>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="subpage">[[Page 2/2]]</div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

In [[Page 1/2]] will be replaced with my contents, which is populated from database.
I am posting an image which will clearly describe my requirement.**Help needed.!!!**
[image]

Comment: This could help: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/page-break/

Comment: Sir, i think creating static pages is not an issue . My requirement is how to add this dynamically? i.e while content goes at the end of the current page.. create a new one!

Comment: Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18743395/7738489) maybe it will help you.

Comment: absolutely !! At least got a starting point :) @DinkarVeer