# how to prevent the tbody from overlapping with tfoot

Tags: html, css

I would like to create a html template that when print in chrome browser, the header and footer will fixed on the top and bottom of the page. The `tbody` will be in between of header and footer. It's height is the total height after minus header and footer. If the `tbody` exceed the height, it will break into next page. Now, I am having issue that when printing the html template, the `tbody` will overlap the `tfoot` and `thead` on the next page, as shown in these pictures. Please kindly advice. My html template is on the below github link.

[image: OverlapFooter]
[image: OverlapFooterAndHeader].

The HTML is in my github repository. Please help to check on this link.

[MyTemplate](https://github.com/shawnteh1711/BPIStemplate/blob/main/template.html)

Below is my code and my reference for dealing page break for large html table.

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763639/how-to-deal-with-page-breaks-when-printing-a-large-html-table#)

This is a short snippet of my code structure

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            html,
            body,
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            table {
                page-break-inside: auto;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }

            tr {
                page-break-inside: avoid;
                page-break-after: auto
            }

            td {
                page-break-inside: avoid;
                page-break-after: auto
            }

            div {
                page-break-inside: avoid;
            }

            thead {
                display: table-header-group;
            }

            tfoot {
                display: table-footer-group
            }

            /* tbody {
                display: table;
                width: 100%;
                table-layout: fixed;
            } */

            @media screen {
                div.divFooter {
                    display: none;
                }

                div.divHeader {
                    display: none;
                }


            }

            @media print {
                div.divFooter {
                    position: fixed;
                    height: 250px;
                    bottom: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    text-align: left;
                    display: block;
                }

                div.divHeader {
                    position: fixed;
                    height: 100px;
                    top: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    display: block;

                }

                div.divBody {
                    height: calc(100% - 350px);
                    position: relative;
                    text-align: left;
                    margin-top: 20rem;
                    margin-bottom: -20rem;
                    page-break-after: always;
                }
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <table style="width: 100%;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <div class="divHeader" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%;">
                            <table style="width: 100%; text-align: left;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><img style="width: 120px; height: 120px;"
                                            src="https://bp.doctor2u.my/assets/img/bplogo.png">
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="vertical-align: top; ">
                                        <table>
                                            <tr style="margin-left: 1 rem;">
                                                <td colspan="2">
                                                    <a
                                                        style="font-family:Helvetica;font-weight: bold; font-size: 20pt;">
                                                        PATHOLOGY
                                                        REPORT
                                                    </a>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2">
                                                    <span>B. P. CLINICAL LAB SDN. BHD. (152314-H)</span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span>[BranchAddress] ,</span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[BranchEmail]</span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label>Tel : </label><span>[BranchTel]</span>
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <label>Fax : </label><span>[BranchFax]</span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan="2">
                                                    <label>GST Reg No. : </label><span>[GST]</span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <table style="width: 100%; text-align: left;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>Client PatientID :</label><span>[ClientId]</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <label>Barcode :</label><span>[LabNo]</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <label>Patient Name :</label><span>[PatientName]</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>Age/Gender :</label><span>[Age] / [Gender]</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="spaceUnder">
                                    <td>
                                        <label>NRIC No :</label><span>[IC]</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>Refer No :</label><span>[ReferNo]</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>Branch :</label><span>[BranchName]</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <label>Client Name :</label><span>[ClinicName]</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>Tel :</label><span>[Tel]</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="spaceUnder2">
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <label>Doctor’s Name :</label><span>[DoctorName]</span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label>Fax:</label><span>[Fax]</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="3">
                                        <label>Specimen :</label><span>[Specimen]</span><span>-sampled at
                                        </span><span>[SampleDate]</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="3">
                                        <label>Received :</label><span>[LabNo] by [ReceivedBranch]
                                            [ReceiveDate]</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <label for="" style="float: right;">Page 2 of 3</label>
                            <table
                                style="border-top: 5px solid black; width: 100%;  border-spacing: 1rem; text-align: center;"
                                class="spaceUnderTable">
                                <tr class="spaceUnder">
                                    <th>
                                        <label for="">TEST NAME</label>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <label for="">RESULT</label>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <label for="">UNIT</label>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <label for="">REFERENCE NOTE</label>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <label for="">RESULT</label>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <label for="">UNIT</label>
                                    </th>
                                    <th>
                                        <label for="">REFERENCE NOTE</label>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <div class="divFooter" style="display: inline-block; width: 100%; left:0px;
                                    bottom:0px; text-align: left;">
                            <table style="width: 100%; margin-top: 1rem;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td rowspan="7" style="width: 20%;">
                                        <!-- [Image] -->
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Results validated and authorised through the Laboratory information
                                        System.
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Results checked and authorised for release
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Test done at B.P. Clinical Lab Sdn. Bhd. (Ipoh) 273-B Jalan Raja
                                        Permaisuri
                                        Bainun,
                                        30250
                                        Ipoh, Perak.
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Tel: 05-2559090 Fax:05-2419226
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Ipoh lab is a MS ISO 15189 accredited lab
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        * Not SAMM Accredited
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4">
                                        <p style=" margin-top: 1rem; text-align: center;">
                                            For further confirmation, please
                                            repeat test with another
                                            fresh
                                            specimen, if desired.
                                            Should
                                            you
                                            have further enquiries, please
                                            contact your nearest BP branch or mail us at
                                            corpcare@bphealthcare.com
                                            <br>
                                            [BranchAddress], [BranchEmail]
                                            Tel: <span>[Tel]</span>,
                                            Fax: [Fax]
                                        </p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="divBody">
                            <table style="width: 100%;  border-spacing: 1rem; text-align: center;"
                                class="spaceUnderTable">
                                <!-- LIPIDS STUDIES -->
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align: left;">
                                        <label for=""><strong>Full Blood Count</strong></label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="text-align: left;">
                                        <label for="">Total RBC</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="">[TotalRBCResult]</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="">[TotalRBCUnit]</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="">[TotalRBCRange]</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="">[TotalRBCResult2]</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="">[TotalRBCUnit2]</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="">[TotalRBCRange2]</label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                               <!-- More row -->
                                <br>
                                <br>

                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>

</html>
```