# how to convert html into pdf using php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting HTML to PDF (not PDF to HTML) using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403820/converting-html-to-pdf-not-pdf-to-html-using-php)

Below is my code, I want to generate pdf by click on `value='print'` where the div `id ='letter'` should contain all the values from the form in html. The div `id="letter"` should be remain in the PDF but it also contain the values from the html form. Suggest any example PDF

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>PDF</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
            function OnEditChange(obj, ev, display) {
                var key;
                if (window.event) {
                    key = window.event.keyCode;
                } else if (ev) {
                    key = ev.which;
                }  

                var dest = document.getElementById("d-"+obj.name);
                if (display) {
                    dest.style.display = (obj.value.length) ? display : 'none';
                }  

                dest.innerHTML=obj.value;
                return key;
            }
            function OnMPANKeyUp(ev) {
                var key;
                if (window.event) {
                    key = window.event.keyCode;
                } else if (ev) {
                    key = ev.which;
                }

                var pc = document.getElementById("pc");
                var mtc = document.getElementById("mtc");
                var llf = document.getElementById("llf");
                var rec = document.getElementById("rec");
                var mpan1 = document.getElementById("mpan1");
                var mpan2 = document.getElementById("mpan2");
                var mpan3 = document.getElementById("mpan3");
                var snumber = document.getElementById("snumber");
                snumber.innerHTML = "<span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">" + pc.value + mtc.value + llf.value+" "+rec.value + mpan1.value+mpan2.value+mpan3.value + "</span>";
                return key;
            }
            function OnMPANKeyPress(myfield, len, dec, e)
            {
            var key;
            var keychar;

            if (window.event)
                key = window.event.keyCode;
            else if (e)
                key = e.which;
            else
                return true;
            keychar = String.fromCharCode(key);

            if ((key==null) || (key==0) || (key==8) || (key==9) || (key==13) || (key==27))
                return true;
            else if ((("0123456789").indexOf(keychar) > -1))
                {
                if (dec && myfield.value.length == len-1)
                {
                myfield.value += keychar;
                dec.select();
                return false;
                }
                return true;
                }
            return false;
            }
            -->
        </script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="termination_centerinner">
                                <div class="innercontent">
                                    <p>
                                        This letter can be sent to your existing electricity supplier to inform them you wish to terminate your existing contract when it expires.
                                    </p>
                                    <p>
                                        Fill in the details for yourself, your meter, and your current supply contract, then click on the 'Print' button.
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <form action="termnotice.php?" method="post">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="print" />
                                    <span class="termination_form_descriptor">From:</span><input type="text" name="name" maxlength="80" style="width: 325px;" value="" onkeyup="return OnEditChange(this, event,'block')" /><br /><br />
                                    <span class="termination_form_descriptor">Company:</span><input type="text" name="company" maxlength="120" style="width: 325px;" value="" onkeyup="return OnEditChange(this, event,'block')" /><br /><br />
                                    <span class="termination_form_descriptor">Address:</span><input type="text" name="address1" maxlength="80" style="width: 325px;" value="" onkeyup="return OnEditChange(this, event,'block')" /><br />
                                    <input class="termination_form_input_without_descriptor" type="text" style="width: 325px;" name="address2" maxlength="80" value="" onkeyup="return OnEditChange(this, event,'block')" /><br />
                                    <input class="termination_form_input_without_descriptor" type="text" style="width: 325px;" name="city" maxlength="80" value="" onkeyup="return OnEditChange(this, event,'block')" /><br /><br />
                                    <span class="termination_form_descriptor">Postcode:</span><input type="text" name="postcode" maxlength="10" size="10" value="" onkeyup="return OnEditChange(this, event,'block')" /><br /><br />
                                    <span class="termination_form_descriptor supplier">Supplier:</span><input type="text" name="supplier" maxlength="80" style="width: 325px;" value="" onkeyup="return OnEditChange(this, event, 'block')" /><br /><br />
                                    <span class="termination_form_descriptor">Address:</span><input type="text" name="sa1" maxlength="80" style="width: 325px;" value="" onkeyup="return OnEditChange(this, event, 'block')" /><br />
                                    <input class="termination_form_input_without_descriptor" type="text" name="sa2" maxlength="80" style="width: 325px;" value="" onkeyup="return OnEditChange(this, event, 'block')" /><br />
                                    <input class="termination_form_input_without_descriptor" type="text" name="sa3" maxlength="80" style="width: 325px;" value="" onkeyup="return OnEditChange(this, event, 'block')" /><br /><br />
                                    <div class="termination_meterform">
                                        <div class="termination_meterform_s">
                                            S&nbsp;
                                        </div><!-- S -->
                                        <div class="termination_meterform_toprow">
                                            <input name="pc" type="text" id="pc" size="5" maxlength="2" onkeypress="return OnMPANKeyPress(this, 2, mtc, event)" onkeyup="return OnMPANKeyUp(event)" />
                                            <input name="mtc" type="text" id="mtc" size="6" maxlength="3" onkeypress="return OnMPANKeyPress(this, 3, llf, event)" onkeyup="return OnMPANKeyUp(event)" />
                                            <input name="llf"  type="text" id="llf" size="6" maxlength="3" onkeypress="return OnMPANKeyPress(this, 3, rec, event)" onkeyup="return OnMPANKeyUp(event)" />

                                        </div><!-- toprow -->
                                        <div class="termination_meterform_bottomrow">
                                            <input name="rec"  type="text" id="rec" size="2" maxlength="2" onkeyup="return OnMPANKeyUp(event)" onkeypress="return OnMPANKeyPress(this, 2, mpan1, event)" />
                                            <input name="mpan1" type="text" id="mpan1" size="4" maxlength="4" onkeyup="return OnMPANKeyUp(event)" onkeypress="return OnMPANKeyPress(this, 4, mpan2, event)" />
                                            <input name="mpan2" type="text" id="mpan2" size="4" maxlength="4" onkeyup="return OnMPANKeyUp(event)" onkeypress="return OnMPANKeyPress(this, 4, mpan3, event)" />
                                            <input name="mpan3" type="text" id="mpan3" size="3" maxlength="3" onkeyup="return OnMPANKeyUp(event)" />
                                        </div><!-- bottomrow -->
                                    </div><!-- meterform -->
                                    <br />
                                    <span class="termination_form_descriptor">Expiry Date</span><input type="text" name="expirydate" maxlength="20" size="20" value="" onkeyup="return OnEditChange(this, event)" /><br />
                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        <!--
                                        function printSelection(node) {
                                            var content=node.innerHTML
                                            var pwin=window.open('','print_content','width=100,height=100');
                                            pwin.document.open();
                                            pwin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">'+content+'</body></html>');
                                            pwin.document.close();
                                            setTimeout(function(){pwin.close();},1000);
                                        }
                                        -->
                                    </script>
                                    <input class="termination_form_print_button" type="image" src="/images/print.png" alt="Print" value="Print" onclick="printSelection(document.getElementById('letter'));return false;" />
                                </form>
                                <div id="letter" class="letter">
                                    <div style="text-align: right">
                                        <div class="filled" id="d-company"></div>
                                        <div class="filled" id="d-address1"></div>
                                        <div class="filled" id="d-address2"></div>
                                        <div class="filled" id="d-city"></div>
                                        <div class="filled" id="d-postcode"></div>
                                        <br />
                                        18th Dec 2012                                        <br />
                                    </div>
                                    <br />
                                    <div id="d-supplier"></div>
                                    <div class="filled" id="d-sa1"></div>
                                    <div class="filled" id="d-sa2"></div>
                                    <div class="filled" id="d-sa3"></div>
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                    Dear Sir/Madam<br />
                                    <br />
                                    <center><span style="font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;">Re: Termination Notice of Contract to Supply Electricity</span></center>
                                    <br />
                                    In accordance with your contract Terms and Conditions, I hereby give notice to terminate my Electricity Supply contract with you, on the contract expiry date for the meter detailed below.
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    Supply 'S' Number&nbsp;
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div id="snumber"></div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Contract Expiry Date&nbsp;</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <span style="font-weight: bold;" id="d-expirydate"></span>
                                                    <br />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    <br />
                                    I would be grateful if you could formally acknowledge receipt and acceptance of this Termination Notice of Contract to Supply Electricity in writing by return.
                                    <br />
                                    <br />
                                    Yours faithfully,<br />
                                    <div style="height:25mm;">
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="filled" id="d-name">
                                                                            </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, please always Google first. `how to convert html into pdf using php` will give you everything you need to know. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403820/converting-html-to-pdf-not-pdf-to-html-using-php

Comment: i already search on google,
but unfortunately it was unable to solve my problem!

Comment: Better than a Google search: do a [Stackoverflow search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+convert+html+to+pdf&submit=search)!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is usefull:

1. https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf
2. http://www.html2pdf.fr/en
3. http://pdfcrowd.com/hub/2011/04/18/convert-html-to-pdf-in-php.html
4. http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2905-PHP-Convert-HTML-to-PDF-using-Web-services.html

Next time, do a Google search.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe tcpdf be your solution. You will see example more than enough:

[look at this](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php)