# Python HTML to PDF with floating divs

Tags: python, pdf-generation

Is there a way to convert XHTML/HTML with CSS to PDF with floating divs?

I have tried pisa/xhtml2pdf in python and dompdf in PHP both are not able to do so.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [html-tables-to-pdf-in-php-neither-dompdf-nor-html2ps-pdf-are-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280173/html-tables-to-pdf-in-php-neither-dompdf-nor-html2ps-pdf-are-working).

A possible path is to use some [Layout (Rendering) Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layout_engine), such as [Webkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) or [Gecko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_%28layout_engine%29).
The rendered HTML page can then be saved as PDF. An example of a tool that uses this method is the [`wkhtmltopdf`](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) project.

(I know, this is not related to `Python` or `PHP` - you can still drive the tool from a script.).

Comment: The concept looks interesting will certainly try it.

Comment: Seems theres a PHP integration on this.. http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/IntegrationWithPhp

Comment: There is a Python integration on this as well
http://github.com/mreiferson/py-wkhtmltox

Answer (score 0):

Found a blog post that does this very thing

http://web.archive.org/web/20130525082452/http://notes.alexdong.com/xhtml-to-pdf-using-pyqt4-webkit-and-headless

got it working rather quickly using the more mature pyqt4 module